# How can I find the optimal filters/kernels in a CNN during training

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

Hi I am implementing a CNN from scratch. Just the convolutional layer with no Pooling and no ReLU. I want to make a proof of concept to classify an O or an X image and find the ideal kernels.
[Dataset consisting only of an X and O image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNOh3.png)

Now with inspection looking for the most common 3x3 kernels I have these four 3x3 kernels that make up the patterns.
[The four ideal kernels that I expect after training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN15f.png)

During training my CNN converges fast to almost zero error and 100% accuracy. Which is logical because the classification problem is really simple. Yet I do not get the ideal kernels. My kernels are as follows:
[Resulting kernels after training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD9sZ.png)

Now I wonder if I did something wrong or not. Do kernels end up independent from each other when training? Should I end up with the ideal kernels or not? Or how should my neural network architecture look like (after the convolutional layer) to get the optimal kernels?

Comment: First: being a common patch does not make something a "perfect kernel", this whole assumption is wrong; second: with just 2 patterns you can literally take a random network,  and just adjust the final bias and potentially flip the  sign to get 0 error, so - you shouldn't expect anything to be "learned" in such data.